# How to forward port for HTTPS

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, kubernetes-helm, self-signed, ambassador

I have a pod with two containers in it - one of them supports HTTPS (Spring Boot SSL with SSC) on port 8081. I want to expose this port somehow so for `/ts` prefix there will be HTTPS support, but not for others. I don't want to configure TLS Termination or something else provided by ambassador, just expose my own HTTPS handling. Is it possible?

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "project.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "project.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "project.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  type: {{ .Values.service.type }}
  ports:
    - port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      protocol: TCP
      name: ts-https
    - port: {{ .Values.service.port }}
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "project.name" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
```

```yaml
...
---
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v2
kind: Mapping
metadata:
  name: {{ include "project.name" . }}-ts
spec:
  prefix: /ts
  rewrite: ""
  host: cluster.local
  service: https://project:8081
  timeout_ms: 10000
  connect_timeout_ms: 10000
```

`curl` doesn't work sadly:

```bash
$ curl --raw -vLk 'https://cluster.local/ts/demo'
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to cluster.local (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to cluster.local:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to cluster.local:443
```

So I suppose `cluster.local:80/ts` is forwarded to `project:8081` but port 443 is not.